# Integer values of $a$ for which the expression $(x+a)(2013+x)+1$ is a Perfect Square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of all Integer values of $a$ for which the expression $(x+a)(2013+x)+1$ is a Perfect Square.

$\underline{\bf{My\;Try}}:$ Given $(x+a)\cdot (x+2013)+1 = y^2$

So $x^2+ax+2013x+2013a = y^2\Rightarrow x^2+(a+2013)x+(2013a-y^2) = 0$

Now I did not Understand How can I solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Is $a$ a function of $x$?

Comment: No $a$ is any constants value not dependent on $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(x+a)(2013+x)+1=(x+b)^2$.

Comment: Using Your Hint:: $x^2+(a+2013)x+(2013a+1) = x^2+b^2+2bx$. Now Camparing These $2$ Polynomials, we Get $a+2013 = 2b$ and $(2013a+1)=b^2$ and Now eliminate $b$, we get values of $a$. Is It Right OR Not

Comment: It is right. ${}$

Comment: Thanks njguliyev , I have Got $a = 2011$ and $a = 2015$